# How to update only a group of fields present in FormRequest rules and ignore rest in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Same table with 2 request files which fills some group of fields respectively

```
 public function update_f1(F1Request $request){
       $projecttable->fill($request->all());
       $projecttable->save();
}
```

Another one

```
public function update_f2(F2Request $request){
           $projecttable->fill($request->all());
           $projecttable->save();
    }
```

Say f1 fills `field_abc1` which is validated in `F1Request`.
f2 fills `field_abc2` which is validated in `F2Request`.

Now if f2 is called it should fill only `field_abc2` 
and not `field_abc1` because its not validated in `F2Request` even if its fillable. Anyone can add `field_abc1` from developers tools.

Yes I can do individually like 
`$projecttable->field_abc2 = $request->field_abc2`
But its better to use `fill` for large number of fields
`$project->fill($request->all())`
In short fill only those fields which are present in Request `rules` and ignore all others even if `fillable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works Perfectly :)

```
public function update_f1(F1Request $request){
           $rules = $request->rules();
           $validfieldsgroup = array_keys($rules);
           $projecttable->fill($request->only($validfieldsgroup));
           $projecttable->save();
    }
```

Comment: Glad to see it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter these fields in Your Requests with `replace()` method.
Like this:

```
class F1Request extends Request 
{
    private $rules = [
        /* rules goes here */ 
    ]

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {

        $this->filter();

        return $this->rules;
    }

    public function filter()
    {   
        $input = array_intersect_key($this->all(), $this->rules);                

        $this->replace($input);     
    }

}
```

If it's common case, than even move `filter()` method to Request class.

Comment: Request::only() already does this. See https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php line 299

Comment: Yes, but - as I understood the question - the goal it to not mention all desired fields all the time, but have something generic, that base on $rules.

Comment: You are right, but you can pass an array to Request::only(). So he would only have need for a place to set the rules array and pass those on to the only function, although perhaps your idea is elegant as well.

Comment: Personally I would probably use Request::only() in the controller, to keep code more readable (for me) in the future. But this is my preference and every situation is different.

Comment: I do agree with that, but I'm not saying he would have to access Request::only, directly, my reasoning applies to the currently extended Request $request, wherever he currently is using it. I just don't really understand why one would add a function that does something it already supports, it just needs a $rules array passed on to it, but maybe I have flawed reasoning due to inexperience and/or incompetence. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: Thanks @Ciccio and SilentDariusz for help. $request->only() was important rest I figured it out and have added my answer which worked for me.

Comment: @Ciccio: My reasoning was to put this logic into request method since it is a part of form request validation and could be used in multiple occasions. Suppouse there is no big difference with using `$this->only($this->rules)` instead of `array_intersect_key($this->all(), $this->rules)`. But then again, `array_intersect_key` is buildin in PHP so why use something higher level?

Comment: @SilentDariusz ok, good point. Thank you, I was wondering if there was something more to it, but that is a wonderful explanation! And a good question. +1

Comment: @SilentDariusz 
 Laravel is not a higher level than PHP.It is PHP.
 Why use `$request->only()` instead of custom `filter()`? 
> Adding `filter()` globally in Request is HARDCODING.
> Adding in custom Request .....Why? laravel has request->only().
>  request->only() helps me recognize that i am not using all fields of table IN MY CONTROLLER itself.
> FILTERING is Controller's job .Request should only do VALIDATION.
> I have OPTIONS to use `Request->only()` or  `Request->all()` or also i can further STRIP DOWN fields `request->only(fieldabc1,fieldabc2)`
FLEXIBILITY is the reason behind LARAVEL.

Comment: There was no debate here on using `$request->only()` instead of custom `filter()`. I said, `$request->only()` instead of `array_intersect_key()`. And in this comparison, it is one layer higher level (one foreach more to do)
Decision where to filter this depends - as always - on what and how You're building. My reasoning is: From this form I want to get that set of data and the rest is illegal => this is job for Form Request. This way every time I will want to use that particular form I would also use corresponding Request Class and it take care about the rest. IMHO. Choose what is best for You

Comment: I justified why I marked my answer as the Correct Solution. Advantages over your answer to use `filter()` . Its not the part of discussion , but it may help others to decide their conclusion. Direct comparison between `only()` and `array_intersect_key()` , i guess but i am NOT aware, may be some constructor/method do some preprocessing of inputs. I Think its safer to use Laravel's `only()` than using raw `array_intersect_key()` .I might be wrong too. Ultimately its preferences...with some awareness about its pros and cons. :)

Comment: @umeshkadam, the `only()` was my answer, but you did not mark that. That's ok. I think SilentDariusz has some good points, too.

Comment: @Ciccio  `dd($request->rules)` returned null `dd($request->rules())` returned array. Brackets ! Then `$request->only()` need just keys so `array_keys` Indeed small things but it makes answer incomplete.You were right and so is SilentDariusz. But  I have justified and also Thanked you guys for help. Hope its convincing.

Comment: And Yes marking my own solution didn't increased my reputation. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use

```
$request->only($request->rules);
```

where `$rules` is the array with fields, instead of `$request->all();`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input